# Getting Authentication error (SE2000) on directory request. iDEAL payment gateway

Tags: php, mysql, payment-gateway

This works properly on Test mode. Error Occurs on Live mode only. iDEAL account activated successfully.

Is MERCHANTID different for Live and Test mode ? or Some other issue is there ?

Comment: Sounds like an issue to ask the gateway provider about

Answer (score 1):

Yes Merchant ID is different for Live and Test Environment.
It could be your SSL Certificate that causes the Authentication error.

You need to install the Production SSL that came from iDeal on your server
and also your own SSL that you've submitted to them.